# Getting error setting and evaluating variables in Chef cookbook

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

Good morning, all....I wonder if someone can help me with this.

I'm working on a Chef cookbook in which I am retrieving values from AWS SecretsManager and assigning them to variables within the recipe and then passing these to templates for config files. However, I think I'm running into an execution order issue where these variables are not being set before the templates are deployed. So, I might have something like this:

```
lifecyclestage = shell_out("cat /etc/chef/bootstrap.json | jq -r '.policy_group'| tr -d '\n'").stdout
stackVersion = shell_out("cat /apps/chef-repo/stackVersion.txt | tr -d '\n'").stdout
webListenerPort = shell_out("aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id MySecret-#{lifecyclestage}-#{stackVersion} | jq -r '.SecretString' | jq -r '.listenerportweb'| tr -d '\n'").stdout
```

I get an error on this:

```
undefined local variable or method `stackVersion' for cookbook
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this? Or maybe there's a way to get variables set and resolved in the proper order?

Comment: Does the value show up when you do `puts stackVersion`? Also, it would help to see the template resource and relevant sample of template itself (in the question).

Comment: No. Puts seems to execute before the recipe even does anything. As for the template, I can't even get to that block because I need previous variables to resolve in order to set the variable that I'll be passing to the template. Note that in the third variable I'm setting, I'm actually using the values for the previous two. That's what's blowing up on me.

Comment: Exactly, Ruby code will run in the compiling phase. So `puts` will show up while `Compiling cookbooks...`. Whereas, the template resource will run while converging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of one of the guys at Chef, I was able to get this working. Ultimately, I ended up creating a shared resource to set these values as node attributes and then reference them throughout the cookbook.

So, I created `libraries/shared.rb` and set up a function:

```
def setEnvVars
  lifecyclestage = shell_out("cat /etc/chef/bootstrap.json | jq -r '.policy_group'| tr -d '\n'").stdout
  node.default['stackVersion'] = shell_out("cat /apps/chef-repo/stackVersion.txt | tr -d '\n'").stdout
  node.run_state['secretContent'] = JSON.parse(shell_out("aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id MySecret-#{node['lifecyclestage']}-#{node['stackVersion']}-secrets --region us-west-2 | jq -r '.SecretString'").stdout)
end
```

Then, I called this function from my `default.rb` recipe.

Finally, the `secretContent` is now a JSON string that I can reference in the cookbook using:

```
node.run_state['secretContent']['secret_key_name']
```

…and get the values that way, which is working great.